# How to update href links in all the html pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css

To explain, I have a blog website, It contains an Index page, which lists out the blogs to read, if  I click on a blog it takes me to that blog page. The index page also has a Recent post tab in the navbar to take me to the recent blog.
Now, I have around 20 blogs which are stored in different html pages which also having the recent post tab in the navbar.
Now, how do I update the 'href' of Recent post on all the 20 blog html pages to the recent blog. It takes time manually to update and save them in all the 20 html documents.

I know this question isn't  related to html specific thing, rather code management I suppose. All the help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: basicly. pHp include() to start with, you'll have only one file to update reused everywhere else included.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to how that can be done?

Comment: You need to learn about php, it is in the first lessons/tutorials you'll find. Try it , theen you can make a clear question about where you are failing

Comment: Fastest fix would be use ajax to load the links for the "recent" and only update one file that gets loaded for any page

Comment: you can start here https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info or https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ajax/info

Comment: wouldnt in this case be easier to use the `<base>` ?

Comment: @HasanPatel nop, its about specific *new* articles :(

Comment: But this will be on the server side, what if I want to do this offline, instead of going and changing then saving, repeating this process for 20 different HTML docs, and then uploading it on the server, how van that be done then?

Comment: ... ajax or php to load those new links from only one file. You need to get familiar with those two to understand the idea i guess.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help, I'll try it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best solution would be to pick some [static site generator](https://www.google.com/search?q=static+site+generator) to learn.

If you want to do it with javascript, one solutions would be to create a single javascript file which generates links and then include that on every page.

most-recent-posts.js:

```
(function () {
  var recentPosts = [
    {
      title: 'post title',
      href: '/posts/title.html',
    }
  ];

  var containerElement = document.getElementById('most-recent-posts');

  containerElement.innerHTML = recentPosts
    .map(function (post) {
      return '<li><a href="'+post.href+'">'+post.title+'</a></li>'
    })
    .join('');
})();
```

And then adding something like this to all pages where you want to show the list:

```
<ul id="most-recent-posts"></ul>
<script src="most-recent-posts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a conditional statement. Something similar to if this HTML tag exists, let it be replaced by the newer HTML tag. Then just make sure that the script is running on all pages.